# How to replace http:// urls with https:// - wordpress ssl

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, ssl

seems to be a simple question, but as i'm not good in MySQL i don't know how to exactly achieve this.

I'd like to rollout my Wordpress-Website in HTTPS:// so i generated a SSL Cert with Plesk Onyx (Lets encrypt) and added it to my site. But i now have to change the old in my database (http://siteurl.com/index.php?site=foo) etc. to https://siteurl.com/index.php?site=foo

I know that there is sth. like a find and replace command in mysql but how do i have to form the statement to exactly get all links (over 200) changed to https://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure on how the wordpress tables look exactly, but your query should look like this, but with the correct tables filled in.

```
UPDATE table SET column = replace(column, 'http://', 'https://') WHERE column NOT LIKE 'https://%';
```

This replaces http:// with https:// for urls that aren't updated yet. It will only have to run once.

Comment: My table in which i have the incorrect urls is called `Gp90g_posts` and the column is `guid` so the statement must look like `UPDATE Gp90g_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://', 'https://') WHERE guid NOT LIKE 'https://%';`?